# could not import requests and bs4

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, upgrade, python-3.7

> I want to import requests library and bs4 in pycharm but I got( no module ) [image]

> and as i click install package I got error

[image]

> > It recommend to update pip 20 to 21 but when I want to upgrade pip in scripts folder I got invalid syntax error

> > > [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on

> certificate verify failed: certificate not yet valid

I'm pretty certain that your computer's clock is incorrect. Check that first. If that's not the case, there might be a broken MITM SSL proxy in the way, which we can't do much about.

As for your problem upgrading Pip, you have a typo. You'll want `--upgrade`, not `-upgrade`. However, that's likely to fail too if you can't establish connections to the server hosting Python packages (including Pip).